# R: Keep getting error messages (Java related?)

Tags: r

I write a line of code and when I run it, it sometimes works and sometimes does not. I don't understand. I don't change anything. I didn't rewrite anything. I literally ctrl+R on the same line, but it works and doesn't work.

For example, below line worked perfectly well one time, but now it is giving me an error message.

```
loadWorkbook("XXX.xls")
```

Error Message:

```
Error: NoSuchMethodError (Java): org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getNumCellStyles()I
```

> 

How should I fix this problem? Error message says "Java" but I know nothing about Java. Please help.

Comment: That function `loadWorkbook` is calling out to Java to read the workbook, but fr some reason then version of Apache POI you have doesn't contain the required method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who have the same problem as I do, I ditched `read.xlsx2` and start to use `read_excel` function from `readxl` library.

`read.xlsx2` allows you to read only certain columns and rows from your Excel file but `read_excel` does not. I still skip rows with `read_excel`. If you need to extract certain columns only, just use `read_excel` to read entire worksheet and then assign a new data frame with the columns you want.